# Taking a forawrd derivative with ForwardDiff

Tags: julia

I am trying to use ForwardDIff to compute the gradient of a function. My code is very simple:

```
buffer1 = 1.
buffer2 = 1.0-buffer1
buffers = [buffer1; buffer2];
K0 = [[100., 200.]  [0.01,  0.001]];
q_sat = [100, 150];
K = exp.(log.(K0) * buffers);

f(x::Vector) = q_sat[1]*(K[1]*x[1]/(1+alpha[1]*K[1]*x[1]+alpha[2]*K[2]*x[2])) 
x = [0.5; 0.5]
g = ForwardDiff.gradient(f(x), x)
```

The first lines are about defining some constants and then I define the function that takes in a vector and returns a real number. When trying to comput the gradient of f I get the error:

**MethodError: objects of type Float64 are not callable**

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 2):

You want to differentiate `f` (the function), not `f(x)` (some scalar), so it must be

```
ForwardDiff.gradient(f, x)
```